# Error when Request.QueryString is empty

Tags: asp-classic

Sometimes users mistakenly redirected to ?Process=ViewImages&PAGEID=. When this happens, they get the following error.

Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: '[string: ""]'

/FLPM/cp/images.cs.asp, line 91

I tried to fix it with the following codes but still get the same error.

```
PAGEID = Request.QueryString("PAGEID")

If PAGEID = "" or PAGEID = NULL or PAGEID = 0 Then
    PAGEID = 1
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if IsNumeric(pageId) and pageId <> "" then
  pageId = Cint(pageId)
else
  pageId = 1
end if
```

this will check if the `pageId` has a value **and** is a numeric value, before accepting it..

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP uses VBScript.  So your PAGEID is dynamically cast, and since it is empty you cannot compare it to a string.  You will also get an error if you try and compare the length, substr and so on.

```
if ISNull(PAGEID) then PAGEID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in VBScript I believe you need to swap this around a bit, and first check

IF ISEmpty(PAGEID) THEN
    PAGEID = 1
End IF

You want to validate that it is empty, not null.  Here is an [article](http://www.evolt.org/node/346) that explains a bit about the way Empty, Null, and Nothing work.

Comment: I tried ISEMPTY before but funny thing happens when I use it. I get 
Type mismatch: 'PAGEID' on the line where I use PAGEID next time.